# Type.registerNamespace is throwing errors when namespace already exists

Tags: javascript, namespaces, microsoft-ajax

In my corporate environment, we are using a lot of javascript. To simplify the management of all this script, and avoid naming collision, we adopted a javascript naming convention for namespaces, which is basically:

> CompanyName.ProjectName.Area.XYZ.js

To create the namespaces, we are using the following pattern:

```
var Company;
(function (Company) {
    (function (Project) {
        (function (Area) {
            (function (XYZ) {

                function function1(args) {

                },
                function function2(args) {

                }
            })(Area.XYZ|| (Area.XYZ = {}));

        })(Project.Area || (Project.Area = {}));
        var Area = Project.Area;
    })(Company.Project || (Company.Project = {}));
    var Project = Company.Project;
})(Company || (Company = {}));
```

Which works fine (actually, this is the output of a TypeScript script).

However, I also have some scripts that use the Microsoft Ajax namespacing function, because this is required by out of control applications (javascript plugin).

I use this declaration :

```
Type.registerNamespace('CompanyName.ProjectName.Area');
CompanyName.ProjectName.Area.ABC = function() {
}
CompanyName.ProjectName.Area.ABC.prototype = {
    function1 : function (args) {

    },
    function2 : function (args) {

    }
}
```

But the call to `Type.registerNamespace` throws an error:

> Sys.InvalidOperationException: Object *Company* already exists and is not a namespace

How can I properly combine both worlds? How can I solve my issue and make the warning disappears?

- I cannot control the order of the script inclusion, as it's dynamically generated by the application.
- I don't want to migrate the whole code to the Microsoft's pattern, as it's quite useless and hard to read. And as I migrate to typescript, I even can't control the namespacing output.
- I also don't want to introduce an alternative namespace to exclude the Ajax's ones, because it will introduce some confusion to all the team.

Comment: I wrote a function called def-once if you're interested. What it does is checks to see if each part of the namespace is registered and continues down the line until its finished; however, the syntax is a little but funny. https://github.com/furiousscissors/OF.Core.js/blob/master/js/of/defonce.js -- defOnce('CompanyName.ProjectName.Area', function() { function YourFn() { } return YourFn; }, window);

Comment: @TravisSharp: this sounds interesting, but I am stick both to the Microsoft Ajax's style (because of the hosting application - SharePoint to be named - that requires this namespace model) and also sticked to the TypeScript output convention. thx for the suggestion anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some months later... I finally had to create two separate namespaces. One for MS Ajax rigid model, one for self created namespaces.

```
CompanyName.ProjectName.Area
CompanyNameAjax.ProjectName.Area
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just try/catch it?

```
try {
  Type.registerNamespace('CompanyName.ProjectName.Area');
} catch( e ) {
   //log it, or just ignore it..
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if this method is not called or fails, the remaining code will fail, because of the rigid model of Microsoft Ajax OOP.